# Summarise data into count per hour, average per day

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I need to summarise a dataset to show the hourly totals per day. The dataset contains travel card transactions for a period of 4 weeks. I would like to see the total transactions per hour (00:00-01:00, 01:00-02:00,...23:00-00:00) for each of the 28 days.

If this is achievable I would hope to resample this to show the average transactions per hour for weekday and weekend, respectively.

The datetime field is datatype timestamp without timezone i.e. 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Is this something PostgreSQL can accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`date_tunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is the key.

#### Transactions per hour

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', datetime) AS hour
     , count(*) AS transactons
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Average transactions per hour

> ... for weekday and weekend, respectively.

```
SELECT extract('ISODOW' from hour)::int/6 AS weekday_weekend
     , round(avg(transactions), 2) AS avg_transactions
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('hour', datetime) AS hour
        , count(*) AS transactions
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`0` .. weekday
`1` .. weekend

`ISODOW` produces 1 - 7 for Mon - Sun. Sat & Sun are "weekend". Integer division `x/6` returns `0` for weekdays and `1` for weekend.

#### Include hours without activity

Above queries only observe hours with actual transactions. To include hours without transactions (no rows int the table) with a value of 0 transactions, (outer) join to a an hourly raster / grid for all of the given period of 28 days. And use `COALESCE()`. Like:

```
SELECT extract('ISODOW' from hour)::int/6 AS weekday_weekend
     , round(avg(COALESCE(transactions, 0)), 2) AS avg_transactions
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2020-12-01' -- first day
                        , timestamp '2020-12-28' -- last day
                          + interval '1 day - 1 hour'
                        , interval '1 hour')
   ) grid(hour)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('hour', datetime) AS hour
        , count(*) AS transactions
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub USING (hour)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The expression `timestamp '2020-12-28' + interval '1 day - 1 hour'` produces the latest hour of interest for the time series.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10ab61c76ad790d2c357d73fa12c13bb)*

Further reading:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194088/939860)
- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)
- [How to get the number of days in a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766911/939860)
- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282639/939860)

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your help on this.
 
date_trunc provided exactly what I needed. Here is a sample of the results:
hour, transactions
"2019-09-23 01:00:00" 1
"2019-09-23 02:00:00" 1
"2019-09-23 03:00:00" 9
"2019-09-23 04:00:00" 13
"2019-09-23 05:00:00" 310
"2019-09-23 06:00:00" 2759
"2019-09-23 07:00:00" 11427

I am now trying to further summarise this to show the number of transactions per hour per fare type (demoted as 'fare_id). The 'fare_id' comprises a number of distinct values for each smart card transaction fare type e.g. 24+, 60+, smartlink, etc. Is this achievable?

Comment: @NualaCarvill Guess so. Please ask your new question as question with all relevant details. You can always link to this one for context, and you can post a link forward here.